# OpenGL: Errors in Case Statements and Order

Tags: c++, opengl, if-statement, for-loop, case

I have two questions regarding my code; 1. Why am I getting this error `'glutDisplayFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(float [],float [],int,int [],int [],float [],float [],float [],float,float,float,float,float)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
1>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type` on my glutDisplayFunc,2. why am I getting initialization and declaration errors on my `i`'s throughout my case statements? I believe that I put my code in the correct order, but honestly this is the first time I've put all of these aspects into one function.

I wasn't sure what portion of code you would need to direct me in the right direction so I posted it all...

```
void init(void);  //function that initializes the window clear color
void DrawsAllIcons(float x[], float y[], int ndraws, int pointsperdraw [], int drawtype[], float colorr[], float colorg[], float colorb[], float rotate, float scalex, float scaley, float transx, float transy); //function to draw the functions in the opened window
void SetupRC(void);
void RenderScene(void);
void settrans2 (float rotate, float scalex, float scaley, float transx, float transy);//function that sets the clear color used to set the state of the OpenGL system


int main(int argc, char* *argv)
{

char header[]="This Bad Boy'll Draw any Icon you can think of";  //set up window title
glutInit(&argc, argv); // initialize glopen utility toolkit
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA); // Set up the display mode with a buffer and colors
glutInitWindowSize(900,650); //Initialize window size and position
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0); 
glutCreateWindow(header); //  Open and label the window
glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene); //points to the fucntion that will be drawing the item 
SetupRC(); // Set the state of the rendering machine
glutMainLoop(); // Call and activate the main
return 0;
}

void RenderScene(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);//note clear color was set in SetupRC
glLoadIdentity(); 
glViewport(25,25,900,500); //set the viewport to the window dimensions   
glOrtho(-7.0,7.0,-30.0,50.0,1.0,-1.0);
float xCoords [7] = {1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
float yCoords [7] = {1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,-2.0};
int numberofDraws = 2;
int pointsPerDraw[2] = {5, 2};
int typeOfDraw[2] = {2,1};
float colorR[3] = {1.0,0.0,0.0};
float colorg[3] = {0.0,1.0,0.0};
float colorb[3] = {0.0,0.0,1.0};
float rotate = 30.0;
float transx = 3.0;
float transy = 3.0;
float scalex = 1.0;
float scaley = 1.0;
DrawsAllIcons(xCoords, yCoords, numberofDraws, pointsPerDraw,typeOfDraw,colorR,colorg,colorb, rotate, transx,transy,scalex,scaley);
}




void DrawsAllIcons (float x[], float y[], int ndraws, int pointsperdraw [], int drawtype[], float colorr[], float colorg[], float colorb[], float rotate, float scalex, float scaley, float transx, float transy)
{ 
int k=0; //index for arrays
int drawTooIndex = 0;

    for (int j=0; j<=ndraws; j++) //runs through
    {
        int whatCase = drawtype[j]; //sees what type of draw
        drawTooIndex +=pointsperdraw[j];
        switch (whatCase)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    glColor3f(colorr[j],colorg[j],colorb[j]);
                    settrans2(rotate,scalex,scaley,transx,transy); // is this where it needs to be?
                    glBegin(GL_LINES);
                    glVertex2f(x[k], y[k]); //sets vertex at the first point at k in the point arrays
                    int i = k+1;
                    k++;
                    for (i; i <drawTooIndex; i++) //pointsperdraw[k] needs messed with maybe?
                    {
                        glVertex2f(x[i], y[i]);
                        k++;
                    }
                    glEnd();
                    glFlush();
                }
                    break;

            case 2:
                {
                    glColor3f(colorr[j], colorg[j], colorb[j]);
                    settrans2(rotate,scalex,scaley,transx,transy);
                    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
                    glVertex2f(x[k], y[k]);
                    int m = k+1;
                    k++;
                    for (m; m <drawTooIndex; m++)
                    {
                        glVertex2f(x[m], y[m]);
                        k++;
                    }
                    glEnd();
                    glFlush();
                }
                    break;

            case 3:
                {
                    glColor3f(colorr[j], colorg[j], colorb[j]);
                    settrans2(rotate,scalex,scaley,transx,transy);
                    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
                    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                    glVertex2f(x[k], y[k]);
                    int n = k+1; //gets index of where to start drawing in the x and y arrays
                    k++;
                    for (n; n <drawTooIndex; n++)
                    {
                        glVertex2f(x[n], y[n]);
                        k++;
                    }
                    glEnd();
                    glFlush();
                }
                    break;
    }
}

}
void SetupRC(void) 
{ // function sets the clear color of an open window, and then clears the open window
    glClearColor(0.560784f, 0.737255f, 0.560784f, 1.0f); // Set clear color to pale green
    return;
}//end of SetupRC

void settrans2(float rotate, float scalex, float scaley, float transx, float transy)
{
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(transx,transy,0.0);
    glRotatef(rotate, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // where to put this in the program?
    glScalef(scalex, scaley, 1.0);

return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has much more to do with basic C++ than OpenGL.

On the first issue: The argument to `glutDisplayFunc()` is a function pointer. The type of the value you pass needs to match the type of the function argument. Looking at the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node46.html), the declaration is:

```
void glutDisplayFunc(void (*func)(void));
```

So the argument is a pointer to a function that has return type `void`, and has no arguments. You're trying to pass a function that has arguments, which does not match the declaration. Which is pretty much what the compiler is telling you.

There's another rational reason why what you're trying to do could not possibly work. GLUT will call the function you pass to `glutDisplayFunc()` anytime a redraw is needed. If it had to call your `DrawAllIcons()` function, how would it know what values to pass for its arguments? It really can't.

On the variables defined inside the `case` statements: The way the `switch` statement is defined, each `case` does *not* start a new scope. Which sort of makes sense, since the code inside each `case` is not surrounded by the curly braces that normally designate a new scope. This means that everything inside the whole `switch` statement forms a single scope.

Since parts of the code inside this scope can be skipped due to the control logic, you could encounter weird situations where the definition (which can include an initialization) of a variable is skipped, but then it is later used without a definition inside code that is executed. Example:

```
switch (...)
{
    case 1:
        ...
        int foo = 7;
        ...
        break;
    case 2:
        ...
        int bar = foo;
        ...
        break;
}
```

If case 2 is chosen, what's the value of `foo`? We skipped the initialization. Does it even exist, since we skipped the definition? Well, it does, since it was declared earlier in the same scope. On the other hand, we never executed the code containing the definition.

To avoid these questions that really don't have a good answer, C++ simply does not allow variable definitions directly inside `case` statements.

If you want local variables inside a case statement, you can always create a new scope by starting a new block. In the above:

```
switch (...)
{
    case 1:
        {
            ...
            int foo = 7;
            ...
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            ...
            int bar = foo;
            ...
        }
        break;
}
```

Now you have a scope inside each `case`, which allows the definition of local variables, and it's clear where their scope starts and where it ends.

Comment: Reto, I figured out my errors in my code, but for some reason nothing is printing like I want it too? Could you give it a quick glance to see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I figured out its my `settrans` that are messing it up, are they located wrongly?